# how to write multi-line jquery code in one variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have mainpage.php and function.php.

**function.php**

```
<?php
function get_header($js){
echo <<END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">.$js.</javascript>
</head>
END;
}
?>
```

That function.php will be included on every php page like the main.php.

**main.php**

```
<?php
include('function.php');
$js = 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.div").click(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $(".tcont").hide();
   var ptype= $(this).attr("title");
   $("#"+ptype).show();
 });
});

get_header($js);
?>
```

As the javascript code may be different in every page, So I want to write down javascript code in a variable in every page, so that variable can be called from get_header($js) function. But I don't know the proper way to quote/write javascript code in one variable.

I don't want to put javascript code in separate .js file and later include it in function.php page.

My question is, how to write the multi-line javascript code in one variable?

Comment: But why do you want it in multiple lines?

Comment: Because jquery code is multiline. If I write the above jquery code in one line it will be difficult to understand for editing at later.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use them as a string:

```
<?php
include('function.php');
$js = '
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.div").click(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $(".tcont").hide();
   var ptype= $(this).attr("title");
   $("#"+ptype).show();
 });
});
';
get_header($js);
?>
```

If you have escape something, you can use \' .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found in come cases, where I have to use both single and doulble quotes for jquery code itself. In that case, what will be the starting and ending tag of string?

Comment: It depends on you and what you want from the php and the jquery or JS. For further info, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and this: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Quoting